# C# Selenium - dropdown menu/ combobox

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium, xpath

I have a problem selecting from a custom dropdown menu.. I have tried both by using the XPath, CssSelector and Id.

I have added a link to the code here:

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm4ob.png)

I think i have to access the div class="SelectBox" in order to access the id='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MP_Blank_Body_MP_Base_Body_MP_TopSideMenu_Body_ctl00_cboBehandlingstype'

but i keep getting errors.

This is what I'm currently trying but without any luck:

```
IWebElement test = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='input']//div[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MP_Blank_Body_MP_Base_Body_MP_TopSideMenu_Body_ctl00_cboBehandlingstype']"));
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to get access to the items in the dropdown?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Post the html of the element you are trying to use that on.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "SelectElement" instead of "IWebElement".

```
SelectElement mySelect = new SelectElement(yourDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MP_Blank_Body_MP_Base_Body_MP_TopSideMenu_Body_ctl00_cboBehandlingstype")));

mySelect.SelectByText("510111 Normalbehandling");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
var select = driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MP_Blank_Body_MP_Base_Body_MP_TopSideMenu_Body_ctl00_cboBehandlingstype");

var stringValues = select.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", select, stringValues[0]);
```

Comment: It gives me no errors, but it doesn't selected anything from the list :)